# Undefined index PHP Error/Warning

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, jomsocial

I am getting the following error on a PHP & MySQL application from Joomla and Jomsocial:

```
[05-Apr-2013 12:23:45 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: query in /home2
/robervl4/public_html/forum/components/com_community/community.php on line 50
```

This did not work out of the box. The application displays products from a database as it should, the only problem is I get this error.

Here is the PHP code of the file, with line 50 being:

```
parse_str($parts['query'], $qstring);
```

code:

```
// DISABLE FORMAT=FEED for now 17Jan13 as requested by Fuqaha
$mainframe  = JFactory::getApplication();
$jinput     = $mainframe->input;
$viewType = $jinput->request->get('format', 'html','NONE');
if(strtolower($viewType)=='feed') {
$u = JFactory::getURI();
$parts = parse_url($u->toString());
parse_str($parts['query'], $qstring);
unset($qstring['format']);
$parts['query'] = http_build_query($qstring) ;

//recompose the URL to redirect
$scheme   = isset($parts['scheme']) ? $parts['scheme'] . '://' : ''; 
$host     = isset($parts['host']) ? $parts['host'] : ''; 
$port     = isset($parts['port']) ? ':' . $parts['port'] : ''; 
$path     = isset($parts['path']) ? $parts['path'] : ''; 
$query    = isset($parts['query']) ? '?' . $parts['query'] : ''; 
$fragment = isset($parts['fragment']) ? '#' . $parts['fragment'] : ''; 

$mainframe->redirect(CRoute::_("$scheme$host$port$path$query$fragment"));
exit('Redirecting to Non-Feed page');
}
```

Comment: Your url may not have query.. on full domain names for example..
You check later if isset($parts['query']) .. but you try to use it before that line..

Comment: its not error , its notice.    query - after the question mark ?

Answer (score 1):

`parse_url` will only include an index if it has a value. I.E., if there is no query, `$parts['query']` will not be set. Test if it is set first:
`if (isset($parts['query'])) parse_str($parts['query'], $qstring);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Can you please explain better what I need to do? Do not understand. @kkhugs thank you

Answer (score 0):

parse_url may not contain the query field. It only contains the query field if there exists a query-part in the URL; so first check there if $parts["query"] exists (isset()).